# Sorting in Nested Dictionary

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sorting, dictionary

I have following dictionary

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>> count=Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,string>>();
```

I get sorted dictionary based on the value of inner dictionary. for example suppose i have following data in dictionary

```
"hello",("world","welcome")
"how",("are","you")
"I",("am","fine")
```

I want it to be sorted like this

```
"I",("am","fine")
"hello",("world","welcome")
"how",("are","you")
```

Comment: why not Sorted Dictionary?

Comment: I am getting data from two different tables and performing some calculation and then storing it in dictionary

Answer (score 0):

You could try this one:

```
var result = count.OrderBy(x=>x.Key);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but it is sorting by key of outer dictionary.

Comment: @Twix you welcome dude. However from the output you have posted that I have understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. You don't need to sort it manually then.

Also note that you can't sort a `Dictionary`, there is no ordering in `Dictionary`, what you can do about it is you can sort the elements in `Dictionary` and store it as `IEnumerable` or some collection which supports ordering.